# passing data from 32bit user program to 64bit linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, 32bit-64bit, x86-64

If a 32bit user program is running on 64bit linux kernel,
and wants to pass a pointer to data in userspace to kernel code. If the
same structure is defined both in user space and kernel space.
will kernel space code be able to decode the data correctly?
If yes how it is done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The 32bit addresses that you use (or *any* addresses that you use, it's the same in 64bits) are virtual addresses. In other words, any kind of address that you use and pass to anyone (including the kernel) is a "fantasy" thing, it does not correspond to real addresses in any obvious way. You don't know anything but virtual addresses.

In order to make this work, the kernel (usually with help from the MMU) routinely translates virtual addresses to phyiscal addresses. For that, every process has a table with all pages that are valid for this process (managed by the kernel).
The kernel maps and remaps virtual addresses to existing or non-existing locations at pretty much every page fault (so basically, all the time).

The kernel can consequently of course do any translations that may be necessary for any pointer you pass it, whenever that is the case.